# Processing a data table from outside the form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a button outside the datatable form which function is to delete the selected row, but the problem is that it returns an empty value of that row in the backing bean, the update of the growl message is done correctly and the action is called too.

However when putting the button inside the form it works fine, but I need it to be in the toolbar which is outside the form.

This is my xhtml code:

```html
<ui:define name="content">
  <div class="row">
    <p:toolbar id="tb">

      <f:facet name="left">
        <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" placeholder="Rechercher..." />
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-search" />
      </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="right">
        <p:commandButton onclick="PF('analyseForm').show();" icon="fa fa-plus" />
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-file-pdf-o" />
        <p:commandButton process="@this,:form:anaDT" update=":form" action="#{personel.removeSelectedAnalyse}" icon="fa fa-trash-o" />
        <!-- this button does the update and runs the action but returns a null value of the selected row-->
      </f:facet>

    </p:toolbar>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <h:form id="form">
      <p:growl id="msgs" />
      <p:dataTable style="font-size:12px;" id="anaDT" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="100%" var="ana" value="#{personel.analyses}" paginator="true" selectionMode="single" selection="#{personel.selectedAnalyse}" paginatorPosition="bottom" rowKey="#{ana.idAnalyse}"
        rows="10">

        <!-- columns here -->

        <f:facet name="footer">
          <!-- this button works fine -->
          <p:commandButton class="btn btn-default" process="form:anaDT" update="form" ajax="true" icon="fa fa-trash-o" action="#{personel.removeSelectedAnalyse}" />
        </f:facet>
      </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  </div>
  <p:sticky target=":tb" margin="50" />
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: try this : `process="@this,form"`

Comment: it didnt work :/

Comment: "this button does the update and runs the action but returns a null value of the selected row". is it `personel.selectedAnalyse`? what is the scope of the controller?

Comment: it's request scopped

Comment: PrimeFaces components use ajax. ajax always require at least ViewScope.

Comment: but why did it work with the button inside the datatable?

Comment: Only the values in the form the button is in are submitted, so the selection being null is logical if the button is not in the form the datatable is in. Put a `p/h:messages` in the form and see if you get errors/warnings

Comment: Please reformat your code into something readable which does not require users to scroll into both directions. Most likely your IDE can auto-format it for you. Tip: make that common practice when coding, you will find it very helpful when you need to debug or modify stuff.

Comment: Yes that's true sorry for that but some lines are long can't help it

Comment: try the process attribute from the first comment but also add `partialSubmit="true"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command button outside of a form can not be used to submit a form. If you want to achieve the functionality you desire, one way is to

1. Have a p:remoteCommand inside the form and bind it to the backing bean method personel.removeSelectedAnalyse and have update="@form"
2. Invoke the remoteCommand from the command button from the tool bar using onclick attribute and the remoteCommand submits the form. Now the backing bean will have the submitted values from the form so you can do the necessary processing and the form will be updated after the Ajax request completes.

Remote Command showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

Comment: _"Command button outside of a form can not be used to submit that form"_ Did you read the other answer and my comment below it? It **is** possible

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'lll try it and see if it works well according to my needs

Comment: @kukultje I agree to your point. Just that the command button also needs to be inside of a form tag to process and submit another form

Comment: No it does not need to be in the same form IF you want to accept that you use non-default behaviour.

Comment: Yes, Not in the same form but it also needs to be inside a form. For eg., commandbutton inside form1 can be used to submit the form2.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the rowKey to the entity type, assigning an unique id to the form. There is no need to process the form at the `p:commandButton` click. I place this button into a `<h:form>`. Command components always must be there. The entity selection done at row click. When you click on the button it uses the preset entity to remove from the `List`. Just the rerendering of the `<p:dataTable>` is needed. And I move the controller into the `javax.faces.view.ViewScope`. PrimeFaces component use ajax by default so the controllers must be at least as wide scope as view.

The facelet:

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <div class="row" >
      <h:form id="toolbarForm">
        <p:toolbar id="tb">     
          <f:facet name="left">
            <p:commandButton value="Delete selected User" process="@this" update="myForm" actionListener="#{myBean.deleteUser}"/> 
          </f:facet>        
        </p:toolbar>
      </h:form>
    </div>    

    <h:form id="myForm">
      <p:dataTable id="usersTable" value="#{myBean.users}" var="user" selectionMode="single" selection="#{myBean.selectedUser}" rowKey="#{user}">
        <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
        #{user.id}
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">First name</f:facet>
        #{user.firstName}
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Last name</f:facet>
        #{user.lastName}
        </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
package x;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Named( value = "myBean" )
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable
{
  private List<User> users;
  private User selectedUser;

  public MyBean()
  {
    users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add( new User( 1, "First1", "Last1" ) );
    users.add( new User( 2, "First2", "Last2" ) );
    users.add( new User( 3, "First3", "Last3" ) );
    users.add( new User( 4, "First4", "Last4" ) );
    users.add( new User( 5, "First5", "Last5" ) );
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    System.out.println( "MyBean.init() called" );
  }

    public void deleteUser()
   {
     if ( selectedUser == null )
       System.out.println( "Selected User is null" );
     else
       System.out.println( "The ID of the User to remove: " + Integer.toString( selectedUser.getId() ) );
    boolean bn = users.remove( selectedUser );
  }


}
```

The User class:

```
package x;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class User
{
  private int id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public User( int id_, String firstName_, String lastName_ )
  {
    id = id_;
    firstName =  firstName_;
    lastName = lastName_;
  }

}
```

The source contains  [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations to avoid boilerplate coding (getter/setter methods)

Comment: you made me realize that the process in the command button was not needed i'm going to try andchange to viewscoped and see if it works

Comment: Using just 1 field in the User class would have saved much more and made room for the getter/setter ;-) And just posting 'it works for me' is kind of not according to StackOverflow 'etiquette. What did you change, why?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your reflection to my faults. I've added the missing contents.

Comment: Getting something in a different form processed by adding it to the process attribute like `process="@this,myForm:usersTable"` is **not** guaranteed to work (it does so by accident and I'd not be surprised if it is removed in the future). It only works on PF commandButton and link and not even the `p:ajax` tags afaik. And it does not work with plain jsf ajax. So I'd not rely on it and just put things in the same form as is normal behaviour

Comment: thank you for your answer i tried making rowkey to the whole value and it didnt work either

Comment: @Kukeltje there is no need to process the form. the entity selection done at row click. When you click the button it uses the set entity to remove it. Just the rendering of the table needed.

Comment: I see you removed it, but then I fail to see (or read in text) the fundamental difference with the original question

Comment: this code works for me. examine it line by line to find the differences to your code. did you import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped? did you modify the selction? do you use the PF components? and so on.

Comment: _"the entity selection done at row click."_ Are you sure? The code in the original question and in your example are fairly similar to the ["Single with Row Click"  example in the Primefaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) and there is no data send to the server on row click". Only when the button is pressed (which in this case is inside the form like the OP states works for him to). The additional value in the `process` attribute you had makes this work for buttons outside the same form

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes I do. If you create an ajax `rowSelect` event you can log : the value of the selectedUser modified yet.

Comment: @Bitman: do you by any change have a 'global' `partialSubmit="true"` in any config file?

Comment: I know how it all works, but but that is NOT in the code you posted.... Please post good code then... Not half-baken...

Comment: it is not half-baken. the code above is working, just you don't belive it :) if you want you can check it out. with or without a rowSelect event.

Comment: The code *as is* does not work for me in PF 6 and PF 6.1... It does when adding the additional value to the process attribute (and for older PF versions you need 'partialSubmit')

Comment: I have created a new WebApplication project in NetBeans 8.1 with PF 6 without any extra configuration and it works for me.

Comment: Strange... What JSF implementation and version are you using then? Mine is Mojarra 2.2.8 (and what is your server?)

Comment: Everithing is the packaged one in NetBeans 8.1 (I don't know it because I'm not at home now). GlassFish 4.1.1. Did you check the source in the current state?

Comment: Mojarra 2.2.12.